# How to switch X windows from the command-line?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I create a script that automatically switches windows? I'm trying to do the same thing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> does.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [wmctrl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl) - see [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/hack-and-automate-your-desktop-wmctrl) for more examples.

**Edit:** Your window manager/desktop environment has to be standards compliant ([EWMH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EWMH)).  [And here are more examples.](https://blog.spiralofhope.com/1042/wmctrl-user-documentation.html)

Comment: Nice! I'll read a bit more about that. Thx.

Comment: Thanks for the link to wmctrl. Unfortunately it looks like your first link is broken. Here's [man wmctrl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl), which might help others.

Answer (score 3):

In cases where **sr_**'s solution does not work, you can also try **[xautomation](http://hoopajoo.net/projects/xautomation.html)**. One of the tools included in that package is `xte` (see **[manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xte)**) - it simulates keystrokes, mouse movement and more. Here's how you can use it to simulate <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>:

```
xte "keydown Alt_L" "key Tab" "keyup Alt_L"
```

Comment: Thx a lot `@rozcietrzewiacz`. wmctrl worked fine. But looks like xautomation can't manipulate windows...can it?

[manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/7/xautomation)

In your link [xautomation](http://hoopajoo.net/projects/xautomation.html) I didn't find no documenation... =/

Comment: It can manipulate virtually anything that *you* can, when you see the screen - just use one of the shipped programs. See my updated answer about Alt+Tab.

Comment: Thx so much [@rozcietrzewiacz](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/9382/rozcietrzewiacz), really very powerfull this. I was needing a way to keep Shift pressed and this works perfectly! Thx.

Comment: is possible simulate `F5` key by xte? Didn't find anything in xte or google yet. This is another [question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22953/how-to-refresh-a-window-by-terminal) that I did.

Comment: @GarouDan Didn't you try? `xte "key F5"` works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer from sr_](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22855/218088) mentioned `wmctrl`, which works for me.

I installed it on Ubuntu 16.04 with `sudo apt-get install wmctrl`. I was able to switch window with `wmctrl -a emacs24`.

`wcmtrl -a $WIN` seems to search for windows with names that contain the string `$WIN`. The search is case-insensitive.

Here is [man wmctrl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl) for reference.